# Как сложить два значения из input между собой

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

У меня есть два поля ввода, подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу суммировать два этих значения на React? ничего не выходит, оценю помощь каждого из вас

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({input1: 0, input2: 0});
const [result, setResult] = useState(0);
```

---

```
function onChangeHandler(e) {
  setInputValues({...inputValues, [e.target.name] : +e.target.value})
}

function onSubmitHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const res = inputValues.input1 + inputValues.input2;
  setResult(res);
}
```

---

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
  <input 
    type="text"
    name="input1"
    value={inputValues.input1}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
  />

  <input
    type="text"
    name="input2"
    value={inputValues.input2}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
  /> 
</form>
```

---

```
 <div>{result !== 0 && result}</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, не могли бы вы подсказать, как я мог бы задать условие, при котором менялось бы сообщение? так как в данный момент с таким кодом ничего не выходит.



const message2 = JSON.stringify(inputValues.input1 + inputValues.input2)  == 12 ? <SuccessMessage /> : <ErrorMessage />

Comment: @quires вообще, то  что вы написали должно работать...только непонятно зачем там `JSON.stringify`. Вы наверное неправильно использовали в своём коде то, что я написал.

Comment: хмм, странно, надо перепроверить, в данный момент я попробовал вставить ваш код, но по какой-то причине div с результатом не появляется

Comment: @quires поменял чуть-чуть, проверьте сейчас

Comment: хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: спасибо, все отлично работает) кажется вся проблема была лишь в том, что e.target.value передавался строкой, а потратил пол дня на это)